# Validate a selector input for a value other than first

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a validation script for a few selectors such as month, day, and year for your birthday. Basically I want the script to run as:

IF the selector is on the first option return false
ELSE return true

What is the IF statement I need in order to return the script false if the first option in the list is selected.

For example,

```
<select>
    <option>FAIL IF THIS IS SELECTED</option>
    <option>PASS IF THIS IS SELECTED</option>
    <option>PASS IF THIS IS SELECTED</option>
    ...And So On
</select>
```

Also, Does any one know how to do this in PHP as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `selectedIndex` to find out which item is selected.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JtCvj/

Answer (score 0):

This is an example

```
window.onload=function(){
    var frm=document.getElementById('frm');
    frm.onsubmit=function(){
        if(!isvalid()) 
        {
            alert("Please select all date values properly!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

// Check validity
function isvalid(){
    var isValid=true;
    var sel_day=document.getElementById('day');    
    if(sel_day.selectedIndex==0) isValid=false;
    var sel_month=document.getElementById('month');    
    if(sel_month.selectedIndex==0) isValid=false;
    var sel_year=document.getElementById('year');    
    if(sel_year.selectedIndex==0) isValid=false;
    return isValid;
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/cgrHw/1/).